# I need a Java timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

i need a timer for my game...
i searched a lot but without luck.

please help.

this is my mouse event:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

     mouseX = e.getX();
     mouseY = e.getY();

     if(shot == false){
         Ink = 0;
     }

     if(ready == true){
     shot = true;   
         // I need a timer here to wait a second and then stop shooting.
     }

}
```

Comment: To the OP: search on `Swing Timer` and your luck will improve. If you still need help after checking out the tutorial, then tell us more about what you're trying to have your timer do, and how your code isn't working.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I saw it after. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, use a Swing Timer:

```
// code not compiled nor tested. It was typed free-hand.
// so it was not meant to be copy, pasted and used, but rather to show you 
// the idea.
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  mouseX = e.getX();
  mouseY = e.getY();

  // don't use if (shot == false). Instead do:
  if (!shot) {
     Ink = 0;
  }

  // likewise, no need to use if (ready == true). Instead do:
  if (ready) {
    shot = true;   

    // turn off your ability to shoot here by setting a boolean.
    ableToShoot = false;
    // start a Swing Timer that does not repeat
    // in the Timer turn back on the ability to shoot by setting a boolean
    Timer swingTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY_TIME, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // allow shots here
        ableToShoot = true;
      }
    });
    swingTimer.setRepeats(false);
    swingTimer.start();   
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Don't use `Thread.sleep(...)` unless you want to put your entire GUI to sleep as this will sleep the Swing event thread.
- Don't use a java.util.Timer. Swing's threading model dictates that almost all swing calls be made on the Swing event thread. A Swing Timer is built to do just this, to be sure that all calls in the timer are called on the EDT, the Swing event thread. A java.util.Timer does not do this, and this will lead to occasional very difficult to debug threading bugs, the worst kind of bugs.
- [The Swing Timer Tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
- [The Swing event threading model tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Thank U!
But theres a problem wiht TIMER_DELAY_TIME,
(Create constant TIMER_DELAY_TIME ...)

Comment: @user2975915: so create your constant then. What's the problem?